# AWS SAM on windows and docker in wsl -docker not recognized by SAM

Tags: docker, aws-sam-cli

I have AWS SAM installed in windows 10 ,How do i make it recognize the docker running in ubuntu20.04 in the same machine?
When i run sam local invoke i get the following error
Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and run

-swetha

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.